# Moving a square on Y-axis in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, java-2d

I was trying to move a square on Y-axis with the help of buttons up "upp" and down "ner". But I am not really good at `JFrame` functions so I need help.

Edit: Fix the issue by defining Y with the second values of component g and increase or lower it by 5 in the buttons action performed and repaint(); them

```
package MoveSQ;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MoveSQJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private int Y = 120;
    public MoveSQJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(120, Y, 50, 50);
        g.fillRect(120, Y, 50, 50);
    }

    private void btnUppActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    }
    Y+=5;
    repaint();
    private void btnNerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    }
    Y-=5;
    repaint();
    private javax.swing.JButton btnNer;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnUpp;
}
```

Comment: First, store your rectangle in a java.awt.Rectangle so you can make adjustments to the position of the rectangle.  Next, add code to subtract from the Y value to move the rectangle up, and add to the Y value to move the rectangle down.  Finally, the Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will show you how to use Swing layouts and components.

Comment: *"so I need help"* What you need is to ask a specific technical *question* based on a problem encountered. If the query is in relation to code, add a [mre] (not just minimal, but also ready to compile / run without changes). Base your attempt on the `Rectangle` approach suggested by @GilbertLeBlanc. I've voted to close this question. If it is improved enough, I'll consider removing the close vote.